# How can I obfuscate a dll when using a Visual Studio deployment project?

Tags: asp.net, obfuscation

I need to obfuscate a dll that is used in a ASP.NET project, the deployment project pruduces a setup.exe which I want to distribute. I have the VS 2008 Dotfuscator installed but when I build the deployment project the project that creates the dll is rebuilt before it is added to the deployment project and added to the setup.exe. Any suggestions on how I can get round this?

Many thanks
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the dependencies using project references.